# Richard Stevens' sock program - multicast clients

Tags: udp, multicast

I've started sock program like this:

```
me@ASUS $ ./sock -v -s -F -j 224.0.0.1 -u 127.0.0.11 5555
IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP set
```

But, when I try to connect a client, I get this error:

```
me@ASUS $ ./sock 127.0.0.11 5555 -j 224.0.0.1
IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP setsockopt error: Address already in use
```

Am I invoking clients wrong? How to connect multiple multicast clients on a single host to a server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this out and bumped into this.  The following commands worked for me (same host or from different hosts):

```
sock -u -i -n 10 224.0.0.4 1234

sock -v -s -i -u -j 224.0.0.4 1234
```

The second is the receiver (what most people call the server but that term confuses me for UDP stuff).